# Styling a specific word in a data gotten from an api which is populated on a screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

After sending a to an API with a 'search value' that searches the database for the value and respond with data containing the value. I want to highlight the given word or search value in the response. The respond is populated to the UI

```
<center>
    {Object.keys(Disp).map((key, i) => (
      <center key={i} className="PublicationCard">
        <span> {key}</span>
        <a href={"https://www." + Disp[key]}> View Publication</a>
      </center>
    ))}
  </center>
```

The Key is a sentence but I want to bolden a word in the key
For example, let say the key is "Discussions about Supervised Artificial Intelligence" and the search query was artificial intelligence, all I want to do is to  bold the search query that is "artificial intelligence' in the UI

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a function to generate multiple span tags.

```
function GenerateSpan({ text, search }) {
    const reg = new RegExp(`(.*)(${search})(.*)`, "g")
    const array = [...text.matchAll(reg)]
    if (array.length > 0) {
        return array[0].slice(1).map((textPart, index) => {
            return <span key={index} className={textPart === search ? "highlight" : ""}>{textPart}</span>
        })
    } else {
        return <span>{text}</span>
    }
}
```

And use in your code :

```
<GenerateSpan text=key search="Supervised"/>
```

And then add style for class "highlight

```
.highlight{
font-weight: bold
}
```

So Finally :

```
<center>
    {Object.keys(Disp).map((key, i) => (
      <center key={i} className="PublicationCard">
        <GenerateSpan text=key  search="Supervised"/>
        <a href={"https://www." + Disp[key]}> View Publication</a>
      </center>
    ))}
  </center>
```

Comment: So everything works fine but what I need to do is make the regex not case sensitive and also even if a single word is found, that should be highlighted, not just the exact match. let say the search word is "Recursion a misunderstood topic" and in the response data  only 'recursion ' could be found, recursion should be highlighted

Comment: You can adjust the regular expression by adding for each word of the search a group in the regular expression.

And change the condition of `textPart === search` by `textPart.includes(search)`.

I haven't tried it but it should be something like that.

Comment: can you please help with the regex

Comment: new RegExp(`(.*)(${word1})(${wordN})(.*)`, "g") Somthn like that you see

Answer (score 0):

The example with `RegExp` works faster, but here is a simpler way.

```
function Highlighter({ highlight = '', children: text }) {
  const index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(highlight.toLowerCase());

  if (index >= 0 && highlight.length) {
    const beforeHighlight = text.substring(0, index);
    const highlightedPart = text.substring(index, index + highlight.length);
    const afterHighlight = text.substring(index + highlight.length);

    return (
      <highlight-text>
        {beforeHighlight}
        <span>{highlightedPart}</span>
        {afterHighlight}
      </highlight-text>
    );
  }

  return <>{text}</>;
}

export default Highlighter;
```

And use it like:

```
<Highlighter highlight={'Recursion'}>
  {'Recursion a misunderstood topic'}
</Highlighter>
```